# Error in a simple program of entering elements at beginning of a linkedlist and displaying it in c programming

Tags: c, struct, linked-list, do-while, singly-linked-list

This is my code for program to **enter elements in beginning of a linked list and print the linked list** *which is working perfectly fine(i am getting correct output for it)* -

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
// this is insertion of a node in begining of a linked list

typedef struct Node
{
    int data;
    struct Node *next;
} n;


void Insert(struct Node** head,int x)
{
    struct Node *temp = (n *)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    temp->data = x;
    temp->next = *head;
    *head = temp;
}

void Print(struct Node* head)
{
    struct Node *temp = head;
    printf("The linked list is:");
    while (temp != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d,", temp->data);
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    printf("\n");

}

int main()
{
    struct Node *head;
    head = NULL;
    int n, i, x;
    printf("Enter  how many numbers you want?\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("Enter the number in the linkedlist\n");
        scanf("%d", &x);
        Insert(&head,x);
        Print(head);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

for context the output is

```
Enter  how many numbers you want?
6
Enter the number in the linkedlist
1
The linked list is:1,
Enter the number in the linkedlist
2
The linked list is:2,1,
Enter the number in the linkedlist
3
The linked list is:3,2,1,
Enter the number in the linkedlist
4
The linked list is:4,3,2,1,
Enter the number in the linkedlist
5
The linked list is:5,4,3,2,1,
Enter the number in the linkedlist
6
The linked list is:6,5,4,3,2,1,
```

now just to see if my concepts of pointers and pointer to structure is clear **i modified the Print() function** in code  as while rest of he program remain same

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
// this is insertion of a node in begining of a linked list

typedef struct Node
{
    int data;
    struct Node *next;
} n;


void Insert(struct Node** head,int x)
{
    struct Node *temp = (n *)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    temp->data = x;
    temp->next = *head;
    *head = temp;
}

void Print(struct Node* head)
{
    struct Node *temp = head;
    printf("The linked list is:");
//    while (temp != NULL)
//    {
//        printf("%d,", temp->data);
//        temp = temp->next;
//    }
//    printf("\n");
     do{
        printf("%d,", temp->data);
         temp = temp->next;
     }while((temp->next)!= NULL);
     printf("\n");

}

int main()
{
    struct Node *head;
    head = NULL;
    int n, i, x;
    printf("Enter  how many numbers you want?\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("Enter the number in the linkedlist\n");
        scanf("%d", &x);
        Insert(&head,x);
        Print(head);
    }
        Print(head);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Now while i did the dry run where i am getting correct result ,the output i am getting is wrong,for context the output coming is

```
Enter  how many numbers you want?
5
Enter the number in the linkedlist
1
The linked list is:1,
--------------------------------
Process exited after 5.156 seconds with return value 3221225477
Press any key to continue . . .
```

while i only made changes in **Print()** function why is'nt the compiler accepting the rest of the elements in linkedlist as input ? assuming there is some mistake in Print() function

Answer (score 0):

Such function implementation

```
void Print(struct Node* head)
{
    struct Node *temp = head;
    printf("The linked list is:");
//    while (temp != NULL)
//    {
//        printf("%d,", temp->data);
//        temp = temp->next;
//    }
//    printf("\n");
     do{
        printf("%d,", temp->data);
         temp = temp->next;
     }while((temp->next)!= NULL);
     printf("\n");

}
```

is incorrect.

Firstly it does not check whether the passed pointer is equal to `NULL`.

Secondly the condition in the do-while loop

```
 }while((temp->next)!= NULL);
```

can invoke undefined behavior if after this statement within the loop

```
         temp = temp->next;
```

the pointer `temp` again is equal to `NULL` (when the list contains one node). Because in this case a null pointer is used to access memory. Or in other case when the list contains more than one node the last node will not be outputted.